# Make a good url without the index with magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, module, overrides, url-rewrite

The url needs to look like:

```
brands/Subway
brands/Mcdonalds
brands/Lego
brands/Barbie
brands/Duplo
brands/.....
```

How can i make this url work where the brand is a variable.

I have tried to make a module but in that case I get an url like brands/index/brands/Subway

I also don't want to make a rewrite for every brand (100+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19446139/2047249). it involves creating a new router inside the brands module that handles urls that start with `brands`.